# Setting index using commonly occurring column value as index of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` as follows:

```
ID  MAHACEB ID  MOROPEX ID  OTX01   ID  MAPOXUB
A0AVT1  48  A0AVT1  23  A0A0B4J2F0  22  A0AVT1  38
A0FGR8  35  A0FGR8  19  A0A0U1RRE5  3   A0FGR8  10
A0JLT2  28  A0JLT2  50  A0A1B0GUS4  10  A0JLT2  56
A0JNW5  35  A0JNW5  23  A0AV96      71  A0JNW5  26
A0MZ66  37  A0MZ66  98  A0AVF1      40  A0MZ66  21
A0PJW6  48  A0PJW6  27  A0AVT1      12  A0PJW6  29
```

I wanted to use the ID as an index if it's value is common across all columns, or fill with NA for the columns with missing ID values.

I tried the following one liner:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='first').set_index('ID')
```

It results in making a list of values in `ID` as row values.

At the end, I would like to have a dataframe which looks like this:
With `ID` as index and all other columns as columns. Fill the missing values filled with `NA`.

In other words,  if the `ID` is common accross the columns, then fill the value in otherwise fill with `NA`

```
ID          MAHACEB MOROPEX OTX01   MAPOXUB
    A0AVT1  48  23  NA  38
A0A0B4J2F0  NA  NA  22  NA
A0A0U1RRE5  NA  NA  33  NA
A0A1B0GUS4  NA  NA  10  NA
    A0FGR8  35  19  NA  10
    A0JLT2  28  50  NA  56
    A0JNW5  35  23  NA  26
    A0AV96  NA  NA  71  NA
    A0MZ66  37  98  NA  21
    A0AVF1  NA  NA  40  NA
    A0PJW6  48  27  NA  29
    A0AVT1  NA  NA  12  NA
```

Comment: Did you leave out the example of what you want things to look like? I think I know what you are asking for, but it also looks like you meant to make sure with an example of a revised dataframe.

Comment: Your data must be shaped in another way, having multiple columns called `ID` isn't possible.

Comment: @Tom What would be the other way you could suggest in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @aschultz, I have edited my question and now added my expecting/aiming output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame is not easy to work with, as the column names are not unique. You should reshape your table into an appropriate format with columns `ID`, `Key` (the values of which would be `MAHACEB`, `MOROPEX`, etc. and `Value`. Then, you can obtain your result with a simple pivot.

Assuming the column names alter between `ID` and `Key`, you could do

```py
# Bring your frame into normalized format
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df.columns)//2):
    key = df.columns[2*i+1]
    dfx = pd.DataFrame()
    dfx['ID'] = df.iloc[:,2*i]
    dfx['Key'] = key
    dfx['Value'] = df.iloc[:,2*i+1]
    df2=pd.concat([df2,dfx], sort=False)

# Pivot
df_res = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='Key', values='Value')
```

Comment: Thank you so much helping to reshape my cpomplicated datafarme! Your solution worked until reshape, but not from pivott_table. However, that is due to multiple `ID` values or duplicate `IDs`. Once removed it is fine. I accepted your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Answer is fairly simple. Do this:

```
df.sort_values('ID', inplace = True)
```

What this does is, it sorts the dataframe according to ID attribute/field and it saves the sorting order since inplace argument is True.
Check out following example:

```
data = pd.read_csv("airfoil_self_noise.csv")
data.head()
```

Output is:
[image: A]
Now as you can see Free_stream_velocity has duplicate values. And following is the way I'm sorting the data.

```
data.sort_values('Free_stream_velocity', inplace = True)
data.head()
```

And following is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, you cannot sort columns,  when the columns are not unique. It will only throw error as : 
`ValueError: The column label 'ID' is not unique.`

Comment: Actually I tried it on a non unique column before posting the solution. And it works.

Comment: The question have multiple column labeled as `ID`. I have now added expected output dataframe